# OPA Envoy - Policy with http.send fails under load

Tags: docker, envoyproxy, opa, open-policy-agent, rego

### Expected Behavior

http.send should be working fine under load

### Actual Behavior

After processing 1000 requests in a given minute, it fails with too many open file descriptor error and resumes after that part particular minute

### Steps to Reproduce the Problem

- OPA version: openpolicyagent/opa:0.31.0-envoy
- Example query, input, data, and policy that OPA was given:
  `policy_response := http_response { http_response := http.send({ "method" : "POST", "url": opa.runtime()["env"]["URL"], "headers": { "authorization": token }, "raise_error": false, "timeout": "3s", }) }`
- Example output that OPA returned
  `{"code":"eval_http_send_network_error","message":"Post \"{url}\": dial tcp: lookup {hostname} on x.x.x.x:53: dial udp x.x.x.x:53: socket: too many open files","status_code":0,"x-request-id":"b643f986-44ca-44c4-95a6-fc4cbe1f5639"}}`

I believe the http.send is creating a new HTTP client on every single request that is causing the problem. Are there any alternatives to overcome this issue.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: With a custom built-in function you can use your own predefined http client.

https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/extensions/#custom-built-in-functions-in-go